# Nasty ANR caused by MediaCodec.dequeInputBuffer

Tags: android, android-mediacodec

I have witnessed and have received reports of a rare but particularly nasty ANR in my app that causes the app to be completely useless unless it's uninstalled and reinstalled, not even Force Stopping the app (which is supposed to shutdown the entire process) can get the app out of the ANR.

I haven't been able to get anything out of the ANR reports, but this one has some useful information. It appears MediaCodec.dequeueInputBuffer is not returning. It is being given a timeout of 200000 microseconds. This is happening in a synchronized block of code off the main thread, in which all operations involving the MediaCodec and MediaExtractor objects take place. The main thread is waiting for the lock to enter a code block containing a call to MediaExtractor.seekTo().

The whole code for SoundTouchPlayable and MediaCodecAudioDecoder can bet found at https://github.com/svenoaks/SoundTouch-Android/tree/master/src/com/smp/soundtouchandroid
The lockup in the non-main thread is happening in MediaCodecAudioDecoder line 181.

I'm not really sure what, if anything, I can do about this. What can I do?

```
----- pid 21484 at 2014-05-01 12:50:08 -----
Cmd line: com.smp.musicspeed

JNI: CheckJNI is off; workarounds are off; pins=0; globals=336 (plus 35 weak)

DALVIK THREADS:
(mutexes: tll=0 tsl=0 tscl=0 ghl=0)

"main" prio=5 tid=1 MONITOR
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x41656e40 self=0x41645450
| sysTid=21484 nice=-6 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1074180436
| state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=936 stm=126 core=0
at com.smp.soundtouchandroid.SoundTouchPlayable.seekTo(SoundTouchPlayable.java:~292)
- waiting to lock <0x422cfb18> (a java.lang.Object) held by tid=20 (Thread-157041)
at com.smp.musicspeed.SoundTouchPlayService.seekTo(SoundTouchPlayService.java:376)
at com.smp.musicspeed.MainActivity$1$1$1.run(MainActivity.java:134)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5184)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1015)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:831)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

"Visualizer" prio=5 tid=26 NATIVE
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x4231ac08 self=0x6a4f1298
| sysTid=21802 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1853423672
| state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=11 stm=2 core=0
#00 pc 0002114c /system/lib/libc.so (nanosleep+12)
#01 pc 0002fc17 /system/lib/libc.so (usleep+30)
#02 pc 00069fd7 /system/lib/libmedia.so (android::Visualizer::CaptureThread::threadLoop()+8)
#03 pc 0000f149 /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Thread::_threadLoop(void*)+216)
#04 pc 00050357 /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::javaThreadShell(void*)+98)
#05 pc 0000ec0f /system/lib/libutils.so
#06 pc 0000d200 /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+72)
#07 pc 0000d398 /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+240)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"Thread-157041" prio=10 tid=20 NATIVE
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x4231dd00 self=0x6c2c0278
| sysTid=21801 nice=-8 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1825959168
| state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=6 stm=0 core=0
#00 pc 00021dc4 /system/lib/libc.so (__futex_syscall3+8)
#01 pc 0000ef54 /system/lib/libc.so (__pthread_cond_timedwait_relative+48)
#02 pc 0000efb4 /system/lib/libc.so (__pthread_cond_timedwait+64)
#03 pc 000098d7 /system/lib/libstagefright_foundation.so (android::ALooperRoster::postAndAwaitResponse(android::sp<android::AMessage> const&, android::sp<android::AMessage>*)+78)
#04 pc 0000a4e7 /system/lib/libstagefright_foundation.so (android::AMessage::postAndAwaitResponse(android::sp<android::AMessage>*)+26)
#05 pc 000724a3 /system/lib/libstagefright.so (android::MediaCodec::PostAndAwaitResponse(android::sp<android::AMessage> const&, android::sp<android::AMessage>*)+6)
#06 pc 00072e17 /system/lib/libstagefright.so (android::MediaCodec::dequeueInputBuffer(unsigned int*, long long)+66)
#07 pc 0001442d /system/lib/libmedia_jni.so
#08 pc 0002044c /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmPlatformInvoke+112)
#09 pc 00054019 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallJNIMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)+428)
#10 pc 000298e0 /system/lib/libdvm.so
#11 pc 00031840 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmMterpStd(Thread*)+76)
#12 pc 0002ed5c /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+232)
#13 pc 000697c5 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethodV(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, bool, JValue*, std::__va_list)+336)
#14 pc 000697e9 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethod(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, JValue*, ...)+20)
#15 pc 0005cc7b /system/lib/libdvm.so
#16 pc 0000d200 /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+72)
#17 pc 0000d398 /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+240)
at android.media.MediaCodec.dequeueInputBuffer(Native Method)
at com.smp.soundtouchandroid.MediaCodecAudioDecoder.advanceInput(MediaCodecAudioDecoder.java:181)
at com.smp.soundtouchandroid.MediaCodecAudioDecoder.decodeChunk(MediaCodecAudioDecoder.java:125)
at com.smp.soundtouchandroid.SoundTouchPlayable.playFile(SoundTouchPlayable.java:373)
at com.smp.soundtouchandroid.SoundTouchPlayable.run(SoundTouchPlayable.java:228)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

"AudioTrack" prio=10 tid=19 NATIVE
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x4231dc40 self=0x6a699228
| sysTid=21800 nice=-16 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1785696352
| state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=0
#00 pc 00021dc8 /system/lib/libc.so (__futex_syscall3+12)
#01 pc 0000ef54 /system/lib/libc.so (__pthread_cond_timedwait_relative+48)
#02 pc 000482b5 /system/lib/libmedia.so (android::AudioTrack::AudioTrackThread::threadLoop()+116)
#03 pc 0000f0d9 /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Thread::_threadLoop(void*)+104)
#04 pc 00050357 /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::javaThreadShell(void*)+98)
#05 pc 0000ec0f /system/lib/libutils.so
#06 pc 0000d200 /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+72)
#07 pc 0000d398 /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+240)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"OMXCallbackDisp" prio=6 tid=18 NATIVE
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x422ca468 self=0x6ef90ef0
| sysTid=21799 nice=-2 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1851258128
| state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=0
#00 pc 00021dc4 /system/lib/libc.so (__futex_syscall3+8)
#01 pc 0000ef54 /system/lib/libc.so (__pthread_cond_timedwait_relative+48)
#02 pc 0000efb4 /system/lib/libc.so (__pthread_cond_timedwait+64)
#03 pc 0000e719 /system/lib/libstagefright_omx.so (android::OMX::CallbackDispatcher::loop()+40)
#04 pc 0000f149 /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Thread::_threadLoop(void*)+216)
#05 pc 00050357 /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::javaThreadShell(void*)+98)
#06 pc 0000ec0f /system/lib/libutils.so
#07 pc 0000d200 /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+72)
#08 pc 0000d398 /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+240)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"ModernAsyncTask #2" prio=5 tid=25 WAIT
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x4244ea50 self=0x6671ffb0
| sysTid=21756 nice=10 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps/bg_non_interactive handle=1787397960
| state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=0 stm=1 core=3
at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
- waiting on <0x42316088> (a java.lang.VMThread) held by tid=25 (ModernAsyncTask #2)
at java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1220)
at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:325)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:157)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2017)
at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:410)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1035)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1097)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

"JavaBridge" prio=5 tid=24 NATIVE
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x41fb6ae8 self=0x6df54688
| sysTid=21744 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1837055584
| state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=3
#00 pc 00021a04 /system/lib/libc.so (epoll_wait+12)
#01 pc 00010e1f /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Looper::pollInner(int)+98)
#02 pc 000110c9 /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Looper::pollOnce(int, int*, int*, void**)+92)
#03 pc 0006e609 /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::NativeMessageQueue::pollOnce(_JNIEnv*, int)+22)
#04 pc 0002044c /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmPlatformInvoke+112)
#05 pc 00054019 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallJNIMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)+428)
#06 pc 000298e0 /system/lib/libdvm.so
#07 pc 00031840 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmMterpStd(Thread*)+76)
#08 pc 0002ed5c /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+232)
#09 pc 000697c5 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethodV(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, bool, JValue*, std::__va_list)+336)
#10 pc 000697e9 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethod(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, JValue*, ...)+20)
#11 pc 0005cc7b /system/lib/libdvm.so
#12 pc 0000d200 /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+72)
#13 pc 0000d398 /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+240)
at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:148)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)

"PowerManagerThread" prio=5 tid=23 NATIVE
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x42340140 self=0x6df63ef0
| sysTid=21742 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1785189064
| state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=3
#00 pc 00021a04 /system/lib/libc.so (epoll_wait+12)
#01 pc 00010e1f /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Looper::pollInner(int)+98)
#02 pc 000110c9 /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Looper::pollOnce(int, int*, int*, void**)+92)
#03 pc 0006e609 /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::NativeMessageQueue::pollOnce(_JNIEnv*, int)+22)
#04 pc 0002044c /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmPlatformInvoke+112)
#05 pc 00054019 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallJNIMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)+428)
#06 pc 000298e0 /system/lib/libdvm.so
#07 pc 00031840 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmMterpStd(Thread*)+76)
#08 pc 0002ed5c /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+232)
#09 pc 000697c5 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethodV(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, bool, JValue*, std::__va_list)+336)
#10 pc 000697e9 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethod(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, JValue*, ...)+20)
#11 pc 0005cc7b /system/lib/libdvm.so
#12 pc 0000d200 /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+72)
#13 pc 0000d398 /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+240)
at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:148)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)

"ModernAsyncTask #1" prio=5 tid=22 WAIT
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x42330dc8 self=0x6d7d36f0
| sysTid=21741 nice=10 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps/bg_non_interactive handle=1718732032
| state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=1 stm=0 core=3
at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
- waiting on <0x4234d908> (a java.lang.VMThread) held by tid=22 (ModernAsyncTask #1)
at java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1220)
at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:325)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.park(LockSupport.java:157)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.await(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2017)
at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.take(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:410)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1035)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1097)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

"FileObserver" prio=5 tid=16 NATIVE
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x42352798 self=0x6ef902b0
| sysTid=21740 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1853392264
| state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=0
#00 pc 00020590 /system/lib/libc.so (read+12)
#01 pc 0008ac23 /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so
#02 pc 0002044c /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmPlatformInvoke+112)
#03 pc 00054019 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallJNIMethod(unsigned int const*, JValue*, Method const*, Thread*)+428)
#04 pc 000298e0 /system/lib/libdvm.so
#05 pc 00031840 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmMterpStd(Thread*)+76)
#06 pc 0002ed5c /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmInterpret(Thread*, Method const*, JValue*)+232)
#07 pc 000697c5 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethodV(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, bool, JValue*, std::__va_list)+336)
#08 pc 000697e9 /system/lib/libdvm.so (dvmCallMethod(Thread*, Method const*, Object*, JValue*, ...)+20)
#09 pc 0005cc7b /system/lib/libdvm.so
#10 pc 0000d200 /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+72)
#11 pc 0000d398 /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+240)
at android.os.FileObserver$ObserverThread.observe(Native Method)
at android.os.FileObserver$ObserverThread.run(FileObserver.java:88)

"Thread-157029" prio=4 tid=21 NATIVE
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x424de938 self=0x6a9451e8
| sysTid=21666 nice=10 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps/bg_non_interactive handle=1786046376
| state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=1 stm=0 core=3
#00 pc 00021dc4 /system/lib/libc.so (__futex_syscall3+8)
#01 pc 0000ef54 /system/lib/libc.so (__pthread_cond_timedwait_relative+48)
#02 pc 0000efb4 /system/lib/libc.so (__pthread_cond_timedwait+64)
#03 pc 00b4fd31 /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
#04 pc 001dbcdf /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
#05 pc 001dbf2b /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
#06 pc 001da16b /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
#07 pc 0000d200 /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+72)
#08 pc 0000d398 /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+240)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"OkHttp ConnectionPool" daemon prio=5 tid=17 TIMED_WAIT
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x42336c90 self=0x6a6f81d8
| sysTid=21533 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1785691240
| state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=3
at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
- waiting on <0x42336d68> (a java.lang.VMThread) held by tid=17 (OkHttp ConnectionPool)
at java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1220)
at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:325)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:197)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:2056)
at java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.poll(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:435)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1035)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1097)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

"Thread-157021" prio=5 tid=15 NATIVE
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x422cfe58 self=0x6a8afb18
| sysTid=21516 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1783564672
| state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=47 stm=6 core=0
#00 pc 00021dc8 /system/lib/libc.so (__futex_syscall3+12)
#01 pc 0000ef54 /system/lib/libc.so (__pthread_cond_timedwait_relative+48)
#02 pc 0000efb4 /system/lib/libc.so (__pthread_cond_timedwait+64)
#03 pc 001e52d7 /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
#04 pc 001d97cd /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
#05 pc 001cff3f /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
#06 pc 001cf485 /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
#07 pc 001d3f4f /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
#08 pc 001cecbf /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
#09 pc 001dc33d /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
#10 pc 001da16b /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
#11 pc 0000d200 /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+72)
#12 pc 0000d398 /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+240)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"AdWorker #2" prio=5 tid=14 TIMED_WAIT
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x422e3f48 self=0x6a6b8988
| sysTid=21513 nice=10 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps/bg_non_interactive handle=1784930528
| state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=6 stm=0 core=3
at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
- waiting on <0x41fc9458> (a java.lang.VMThread) held by tid=14 (AdWorker #2)
at java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1220)
at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:325)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:197)
at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferQueue.awaitFulfill(SynchronousQueue.java:733)
at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferQueue.transfer(SynchronousQueue.java:664)
at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue.poll(SynchronousQueue.java:910)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1035)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1097)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

"AdWorker #1" prio=5 tid=13 TIMED_WAIT
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x42335668 self=0x6c0cec20
| sysTid=21511 nice=10 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps/bg_non_interactive handle=1812787320
| state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=2 stm=0 core=3
at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
- waiting on <0x42335808> (a java.lang.VMThread) held by tid=13 (AdWorker #1)
at java.lang.Thread.parkFor(Thread.java:1220)
at sun.misc.Unsafe.park(Unsafe.java:325)
at java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:197)
at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferQueue.awaitFulfill(SynchronousQueue.java:733)
at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue$TransferQueue.transfer(SynchronousQueue.java:664)
at java.util.concurrent.SynchronousQueue.poll(SynchronousQueue.java:910)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1035)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1097)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

"CleanupReference" daemon prio=5 tid=12 WAIT
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x4232b618 self=0x6c2bf8e0
| sysTid=21510 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1814822200
| state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=0
at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
- waiting on <0x4232b550> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue)
at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:401)
at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:102)
at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:73)
at com.android.org.chromium.content.common.CleanupReference$1.run(CleanupReference.java:48)

"Thread-157017" prio=5 tid=11 NATIVE
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x423293a0 self=0x6c2b38e0
| sysTid=21499 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1782253760
| state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=2
#00 pc 00021dc4 /system/lib/libc.so (__futex_syscall3+8)
#01 pc 0000ef54 /system/lib/libc.so (__pthread_cond_timedwait_relative+48)
#02 pc 0000efb4 /system/lib/libc.so (__pthread_cond_timedwait+64)
#03 pc 001d97d5 /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
#04 pc 001d97f5 /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
#05 pc 001cff0f /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
#06 pc 001cf485 /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
#07 pc 001d3f4f /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
#08 pc 001cecbf /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
#09 pc 008e9893 /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
#10 pc 008e9c8b /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
#11 pc 001dc33d /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
#12 pc 001da16b /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
#13 pc 0000d200 /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+72)
#14 pc 0000d398 /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+240)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"Thread-157015" prio=5 tid=10 NATIVE
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x42325e00 self=0x6a42b578
| sysTid=21504 nice=-6 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1782737400
| state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=18 stm=10 core=0
#00 pc 00021a04 /system/lib/libc.so (epoll_wait+12)
#01 pc 001e7ff3 /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
#02 pc 001e71e5 /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
#03 pc 001e010f /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
#04 pc 001cf485 /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
#05 pc 001d3f4f /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
#06 pc 001cecbf /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
#07 pc 008e9901 /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
#08 pc 008e9cb3 /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
#09 pc 001dc33d /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
#10 pc 001da16b /system/lib/libwebviewchromium.so
#11 pc 0000d200 /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+72)
#12 pc 0000d398 /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+240)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"Binder_2" prio=5 tid=9 NATIVE
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x41b878e8 self=0x6659d530
| sysTid=21495 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1717162728
| state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=1 stm=0 core=0
#00 pc 00020850 /system/lib/libc.so (__ioctl+8)
#01 pc 0002d187 /system/lib/libc.so (ioctl+14)
#02 pc 0001d561 /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::talkWithDriver(bool)+140)
#03 pc 0001dc6b /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::getAndExecuteCommand()+6)
#04 pc 0001dd01 /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::joinThreadPool(bool)+48)
#05 pc 00022019 /system/lib/libbinder.so
#06 pc 0000f149 /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Thread::_threadLoop(void*)+216)
#07 pc 00050357 /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::javaThreadShell(void*)+98)
#08 pc 0000ec0f /system/lib/libutils.so
#09 pc 0000d200 /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+72)
#10 pc 0000d398 /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+240)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"Binder_1" prio=5 tid=8 NATIVE
| group="main" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x41b87748 self=0x6659c8b0
| sysTid=21494 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1717159528
| state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=1 stm=0 core=0
#00 pc 00020850 /system/lib/libc.so (__ioctl+8)
#01 pc 0002d187 /system/lib/libc.so (ioctl+14)
#02 pc 0001d561 /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::talkWithDriver(bool)+140)
#03 pc 0001dc6b /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::getAndExecuteCommand()+6)
#04 pc 0001dd01 /system/lib/libbinder.so (android::IPCThreadState::joinThreadPool(bool)+48)
#05 pc 00022019 /system/lib/libbinder.so
#06 pc 0000f149 /system/lib/libutils.so (android::Thread::_threadLoop(void*)+216)
#07 pc 00050357 /system/lib/libandroid_runtime.so (android::AndroidRuntime::javaThreadShell(void*)+98)
#08 pc 0000ec0f /system/lib/libutils.so
#09 pc 0000d200 /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+72)
#10 pc 0000d398 /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+240)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"FinalizerWatchdogDaemon" daemon prio=5 tid=7 WAIT
| group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x41b830e8 self=0x6659bbc8
| sysTid=21493 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1717157920
| state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=0
at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
- waiting on <0x41660478> (a java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerWatchdogDaemon)
at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:364)
at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerWatchdogDaemon.waitForObject(Daemons.java:230)
at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerWatchdogDaemon.run(Daemons.java:207)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

"FinalizerDaemon" daemon prio=5 tid=6 WAIT
| group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x41b82f90 self=0x6659a768
| sysTid=21492 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1717152704
| state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=1 stm=0 core=0
at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
- waiting on <0x4164b7d8> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue)
at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:401)
at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:102)
at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:73)
at java.lang.Daemons$FinalizerDaemon.run(Daemons.java:170)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

"ReferenceQueueDaemon" daemon prio=5 tid=5 WAIT
| group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x41b82e28 self=0x66599ec0
| sysTid=21491 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1717150488
| state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=3
at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
- waiting on <0x4164b700> 
at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:364)
at java.lang.Daemons$ReferenceQueueDaemon.run(Daemons.java:130)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)

"Compiler" daemon prio=5 tid=4 VMWAIT
| group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x41b82d38 self=0x415b4258
| sysTid=21490 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1096499216
| state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=11 stm=9 core=0
#00 pc 00021dc4 /system/lib/libc.so (__futex_syscall3+8)
#01 pc 0000ef54 /system/lib/libc.so (__pthread_cond_timedwait_relative+48)
#02 pc 0000efb4 /system/lib/libc.so (__pthread_cond_timedwait+64)
#03 pc 00080937 /system/lib/libdvm.so
#04 pc 0005c0fd /system/lib/libdvm.so
#05 pc 0000d200 /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+72)
#06 pc 0000d398 /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+240)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"Signal Catcher" daemon prio=5 tid=3 RUNNABLE
| group="system" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x41b82c40 self=0x648b9120
| sysTid=21489 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1772267456
| state=R schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=2 stm=2 core=3
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

"GC" daemon prio=5 tid=2 VMWAIT
| group="system" sCount=1 dsCount=0 obj=0x41b82b60 self=0x648bc070
| sysTid=21488 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps handle=1686879040
| state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=2 stm=0 core=0
#00 pc 00021dc4 /system/lib/libc.so (__futex_syscall3+8)
#01 pc 0000ef54 /system/lib/libc.so (__pthread_cond_timedwait_relative+48)
#02 pc 0000efb4 /system/lib/libc.so (__pthread_cond_timedwait+64)
#03 pc 0007eff3 /system/lib/libdvm.so
#04 pc 0005c0fd /system/lib/libdvm.so
#05 pc 0000d200 /system/lib/libc.so (__thread_entry+72)
#06 pc 0000d398 /system/lib/libc.so (pthread_create+240)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)

NATIVE THREADS:
".smp.musicspeed" sysTid=21498 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps
| state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=2

".smp.musicspeed" sysTid=21500 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps
| state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=2

".smp.musicspeed" sysTid=21501 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps
| state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=2

".smp.musicspeed" sysTid=21502 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps
| state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=2

".smp.musicspeed" sysTid=21503 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps
| state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=0

".smp.musicspeed" sysTid=21505 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps
| state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=3

".smp.musicspeed" sysTid=21506 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps
| state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=3

".smp.musicspeed" sysTid=21507 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps
| state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=3

".smp.musicspeed" sysTid=21508 nice=0 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps
| state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=0 stm=0 core=3

".smp.musicspeed" sysTid=21517 nice=-6 sched=0/0 cgrp=apps
| state=S schedstat=( 0 0 0 ) utm=1 stm=1 core=0
```

Comment: As you can see from the stack trace for tid=20, it's sitting in `postAndAwaitResponse()`, which is waiting for activity from another thread.  All of the actual MediaCodec work is done in the mediaserver process.  It's possible that the mediaserver process has locked up, which is leading to the ANR in your process... and because it's still locked up, killing and restarting your app doesn't help.  I don't know why uninstalling your app would change anything; I'd think a reboot would be the necessary fix.

Comment: A full bugreport (from a "developer" device) will have a mediaserver stack trace.  Without that it's hard to know for sure what's going on.  Knowing what device and version of Android is affected might prove interesting.

Comment: It's an HTC One GPE stock 4.4.2

Answer (score 0):

### EDIT 1:

ANRs are triggered by either of the following conditions.

- No response to an input event (such as key press or screen touch events) within 5 seconds.
- A BroadcastReceiver hasn't finished executing within 10 seconds.

Since your timeout is set to a sub-second value, it's not likely to be the direct source of your problem. The problem is more likely to be a result of the synchronization blocks. If you have code running on the main thread that's being delayed due to thread synchronization, that could easily trigger one of the ANR conditions.

I'll take a look at your actual code a bit later tonight if nobody else has already determined the problem.

### EDIT 2:

Looking at the ANR dump in the question and the code, the issue appears to be caused by lock-contention on `decodeLock` when trying to do a seek. The thread holding the lock is a native thread gotten to by the path SoundTouchPlayable.run()->SoundTouchPlayable.playFile()->MediaCodecAudioDecoder.decodeChunk()->MediaCodecAudioDecoder.advanceInput().

To arrive at that, I looked for "waiting" in the ANR dump. Those that are on `Object.wait` aren't a problem; they're just waiting for more messages. The only one that's different is `waiting to lock <0x422cfb18> (a java.lang.Object) held by tid=20`. Then it's just a matter of looking to see which threads has `tid=20`.

I suggest determining how/why those two different threads could be running at the same time. Then working out a plan to keep them from do so or if it's OK that they run at the same time, changing the synchronization locks to allow it.

To address the fact that you have to do an uninstall to recover, consider that a simple force-stop might be leaving some process running. An uninstall will be more aggressive about finding and killing all processes running under that user id (each app has its own).

Comment: 200,000 microseconds is 0.2 seconds, 200 milliseconds. It's possible it's a typo in the documentation and the parameter is really in milliseconds, but I'm pretty sure it's not due to other experience with this timeout. I guess it's worth coming up with a test to make sure though.

Comment: I stand corrected. I completely misread it as milliseconds. And then compounded my mistake by typing microseconds in my response where I meant milliseconds.